# How to intercept a 404 error

Tags: hooks, 404-error

I'd like to intercept 404 errors and do some things before to show the 404 error page.

How can intercept the 404 error?

Comment: Are you getting a WordPress error page or a server one?

Comment: Think I'm linking to a post that doesn't exist: I want to intercept that kind of 404. Then, if possible, I'd like to know the passed id or the passed slug and use it to do other things.

Comment: But you didn't answer the question: Are you seeing WordPress 404 pages or server generated ones? Or what, exactly, if neither of those?

Comment: Currently I haven't the error: I'm developing a plugin that has to intercept 404 errors generated by wordpress itself when the url is of a post that doesn't exist. I don't have a real 404 error. I publish a post (call it A) and this post links to the post "B". Post "B" doesn't exist (or is scheduled or only a draft or its link is wrong). I want to intercept the 404 error generated when I go from Post A to Post B. I produce the error linking from Post A to an inexistent post, http://example.com/?p=1234567890 or http://example.com/non-existent-post

Comment: I assume you've read: https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Error_404_Page

Comment: The `template_include` or `template_redirect` hooks might be useful too. Really, your question/problem is pretty vague at this point.

Comment: Maybe it's a vague question, but the point is that i want to intercept the 404 error in a plugin I'm writing: i think is sufficiently complete as request, or not? This is my first plugin, so maybe I'm missing some information... Anyway, I've read that page, but as said, I want to intercept the 404 error in a plugin, don't want to edit a 404 template. I want my functionality be available independently of the theme in use...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As was mentioned in a comment, `template_redirect` would be an appropriate hook for intercepting a 404 before the template is loaded.

```
function wpd_do_stuff_on_404(){
    if( is_404() ){
        // do stuff
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpd_do_stuff_on_404' );
```

Refer to the [Action Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) for the general order of actions on the front end. The main query runs between the `posts_selection` and `wp` actions, so that is the earliest you can determine that a request is a 404. The template is then loaded after `template_redirect`, so it's too late to set headers after that point.

Comment: Thanks!  This is super helpful!  One note though: I would suggest checking for if(!is_404()) { return; } instead, in order to reduce indentation.

Answer (score -1):

Using below code you can directly redirect on home page when 404 call, please remove all code from the 404.php file and add below code.

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: ".get_bloginfo('url'));
exit();
?>
```

Comment: This is not what I asked and, more, it is also wrong as solution as, to do the same exact thing, it is sufficient to use `.htaccess`, without the need to edit any code.

Anyway, thankyou for the reply.