# How to intercept not found URL, parse it, and generate dynamic result?

Tags: routing

I would like to catch the URL handler after it fails to find any matching page, but before it handles the response as a 404.

Then, based on whether I match a regex in the URL, I might like to generate dynamic content to be returned as the result.  If I don't match the URL, then I would allow the 404 page.

For example, assume my users each have a special unique ID, such as "x1234" or "x5533".  I want `example.com/x5533` to result in my custom function being called so I can generate content related to my user (such as a limited public profile).  I don't want the URL to change from the viewer's perspective - I just want to generate content for that one request.

If no such user exists, or the URL doesn't match anything else on the site (first), then I would like Wordpress to send the usual 404 page.

I have seen the URL rewrite function, but I don't believe I want to rewrite the URL.  I just want to handle it and dynamically generate output.

Comment: A rewrite rule is a regex pattern that gets matched against the requested URL, it sounds like that’s exactly what you’re after.

Comment: Intercepting a 404 for additional handling: 
 https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/194348/how-to-intercept-a-404-error

Comment: @Milo - Indeed, a rewrite rule does match, but it requires "The URL you would like to actually fetch".  I don't want to fetch any URL, nor do I want to change the URL.  I just want to handle this myself and generate dynamic content.

Comment: @jdm2112 - ahh ok, so I would actually just put a hook into the 404 handler, then do what I want (and not return a 404) if I like the URL...

Comment: "The URL you would like to actually fetch" is not actually a URL, it's the data you extract from the URL that you would use later to serve the appropriate content. Intercepting a request WordPress has already deemed a 404 just wastes a trip to the database. If you know a URL is for your custom result, it's better to short-circuit that process before it ever happens.